# Shoutcast player Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, shoutcast

I want to make a custom media player for windows phone 7, which can play shoutcast radio channel in http://s2.voscast.com:8164. I have tried with this code and it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me ?

```
namespace MediaticPlayer
{
    public partial class RadioPlayer : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public RadioPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher() { Media = new Uri("http://s2.voscast.com:8164", UriKind.Absolute) };
            mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a link to the server summary page. Unlike Shoutcast 1, SC2 servers allow for multiple streams/mountpoints. Because of this ability, SC2 streams are not situated in the root like SC1 streams. See how you get on with the url to your actual stream:

```
http://198.178.123.5:8164/stream/1/
```

Comment: I have tried with this format and it shows me an error saying it can't play this file on the phone.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: @enadun: I find it very surprising that `audio/mpeg` would not be supported. Perhaps instead, use the playlist url: http://s2.voscast.com:8164/listen.pls?sid=1

Comment: It's also not working :(
Yes! I also found that, we can't directly play on media player through the stream URL. We have to setup a mechanism to get the stream of data to be passed to the application continuously.
But I don't know how.